# Arctic Fox: Android emulator doesn't have back button

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

When creating emulator in AVD manager, `enable hardware button` was checked but there is still no hardware button below. It is android studio Arctic Fox and API level 30. Anything wrong with android studio? It is on macOS Big Sur.

[image]

Comment: Don't you have [this panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li2qW.png) next to the emulator window?

Comment: Open Android settings in the emulator -> System -> Gestures -> System Navigation -> 3-button Navigation

Comment: If you are selecting the `enable hardware button` you may also want to select the `Enable Device Frame` as well. Because I think Android hides the soft navigation buttons if there are hardware buttons available in the device.

Comment: Yes, there is the panel on the side of emulator. Also the Device Frame was enabled. OK. there is back button on the panel. The emulator seems missing quite a few icons like setting and gallery.

Comment: Interestingly, I didn't find System icon on emulator on panel and on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You may try re-installing the emulator...
In case it doesn't work, check in your Emulator Android Settings, like their in our Android Phone that Full-Screen Display is disabled.


### Settings > Display > Full screen display > Enable Buttons (Disable Full screen gestures)

Comment: Newly created emulator still does not have the back button (following the doc on android.com). The emulator created in windows platform does have the back button.

Answer (score 0):

When API level is reduced to 27, the emulator has hardware button and other features Android phone has.